# Firebase not working in ionic iOS but its working fine in Android and localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, firebase, ionic3

```js
 try {
      firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error,'error');
    }
```

I have setup the Firebase account which I am using in Android ionic. I don't create any additional account for iOS

Comment: does `console.log(error,'error');` output anything?

Comment: Connection::waitForSyncReply: Timed-out while waiting for reply, id = 13